# Adding Restrictions to a Password in HTML?

Tags: html, passwords

I'm making a form that has the user enter a username and password.

Is there any way to add restrictions to a password, *only* using HTML? (NOT looking to use Javascript, PHP, etc.) I want it to "force" the user to have to input at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase letter, etc.

I don't know if it matters, but here's what I have so far:

```
<b>Password:</b>
   <input type="password" "size=20" name="pswd" min="7" max="15">
```

Comment: Take a look at the `pattern` attribute

Comment: Keep in mind that complex password rules will usually not lead to more safe passwords, important is only a minimum length. People cannot remember tons of strong passwords, and such rules can interfere with good password schemes. People can get very inventive to bypass such rules, e.g. by using weak passwords like "Password-2016". Often you end up with weaker passwords instead of stronger ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an input pattern. Note that this is specific to HTML5.

```
<form>
<input type="password" name="pass" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

See: http://www.codingcage.com/2015/03/html5-form-validations-with-pattern.html

Comment: When I was researching I saw a bit of info on patterns and couldn't quite understand what it meant. Thanks so much for your example, I think I understand it a bit more! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend handling validation with just HTML, as anyone with a little technical knowledge could edit a page's HTML with Inspect Element in any modern browser. This means they could easily bypass any restrictions you placed on a password if they so wished.

Final validation should occur with a server-side language such as PHP, which can't be edited by the user, unless it isn't imperative that the data match your specifications. Even using JavaScript for validation still has its weaknesses. Server-side is the only way to be sure the data going into your database meets your standards.

Comment: Thanks for the tidbit! I appreciate it when I go on to more coding! For now I'm just a beginner doing a little HTML work in class so I'm not hitting things hard and heavy just yet, but I'm really fascinated by that info! I never knew that, thanks! ;)

Comment: You're welcome! If you're simply working on class projects, the type of validation you use shouldn't matter unless your instructor specifies it. But for published websites with a database, there are always these factors to consider. If you want to see it in action, just right-click anywhere in a webpage and select Inspect Element. You can manipulate any part of the HTML/CSS. Great for troubleshooting, experimenting, and snagging sample code to play with. Have fun!